# SQL Server Unique Composite Key of Two Field With Second Field Auto-Increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique, auto-increment

I have the following problem, I want to have **Composite Primary Key** like:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`base`, `id`);
```

for which when I insert a `base` the id to be auto-incremented based on the previous `id` for the same `base`

Example:

```
base   id
A      1
A      2
B      1
C      1
```

Is there a way when I say:
`INSERT INTO table(base) VALUES ('A')`
to insert a new record with `id` 3 because that is the next id for `base` 'A'?

The resulting table should be:

```
base   id
A      1
A      2
B      1
C      1
A      3
```

Is it possible to do it on the DB exactly since if done programmatically it could cause racing conditions.

**EDIT**

The `base` currently represents a company, the `id` represents invoice number. There should be auto-incrementing invoice numbers for each company but there could be cases where two companies have invoices with the same number. Users logged with a company should be able to sort, filter and search by those invoice numbers.

Comment: It's be far easier to just have a plain `_ID` column using normal `IDENTITY` behind the scenes and then hide this table behind a view that does `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY base ORDER BY _ID) as ID`.

Comment: This is do-able but very difficult to get exactly right (see my comment to @arjun, below).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is not really smart if I have sorting/filtering since I have to generate them in a different way. Additionally I want to be able to search by the `id` so if I don't save it I have to use indexes I guess which makes things even worse.

Comment: Why do you feel you need this?  There are some use cases that require actually storing it, but these are rare.  What does this information represent?  If you want a searchable id, you want a regular auto-gen (unique value) column.  You want indices anyways.  What is it you see as a "benefit" in this approach?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse the `base` represents a company, the `id` represents invoice number. There should be auto-incrementing invoice numbers for each company but there could be cases where two companies have invoices with the same number. Users logged with a company should be able to sort, filter and search by those invoices.

Comment: Ouch.  Invoice numbers can be worse - often they're **not allowed to have gaps**.  This _is_ a legitimate business case for these - I've been thinking about a solution though...

Comment: I asked a similar question (I did not found this one before asking) and got an interresting answer that works pretty well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498675/how-to-create-an-auto-increment-column-that-is-segmented-by-an-other-column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ever since someone posted a similar question, I've been pondering this.  The first problem is that DBs don't provide "partitionable" sequences (that would restart/remember based on different keys).  The second is that the `SEQUENCE` objects that *are* provided are geared around fast access, and can't be rolled back (ie, you *will* get gaps).  This essentially this rules out using a built-in utility... meaning we have to roll our own.

The first thing we're going to need is a table to store our sequence numbers.  This can be fairly simple:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice_Sequence (base CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                               invoiceNumber INTEGER);
```

In reality the `base` column should be a foreign-key reference to whatever table/id defines the business(es)/entities you're issuing invoices for.  In this table, you want entries to be unique per issued-entity.

Next, you want a stored proc that will take a key (`base`) and spit out the next number in the sequence (`invoiceNumber`).  The set of keys necessary will vary (ie, some invoice numbers must contain the year or full date of issue), but the base form for this situation is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Next_Invoice_Number @baseKey CHAR(1), 
                                     @invoiceNumber INTEGER OUTPUT 
AS MERGE INTO Invoice_Sequence Stored
              USING (VALUES (@baseKey)) Incoming(base)
                 ON Incoming.base = Stored.base
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Stored.invoiceNumber = Stored.invoiceNumber + 1
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (base) VALUES(@baseKey)
   OUTPUT INSERTED.invoiceNumber ;;
```

Note that:

1. You **must** run this in a serialized transaction
2. The transaction **must** be the same one that's inserting into the destination (invoice) table.

That's right, you'll still get blocking per-business when issuing invoice numbers.  You **can't** avoid this if invoice numbers must be sequential, with no gaps - until the row is actually committed, it might be rolled back, meaning that the invoice number wouldn't have been issued.

Now, since you don't want to have to remember to call the procedure for the entry, wrap it up in a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Populate_Invoice_Number ON Invoice INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
  DECLARE @invoiceNumber INTEGER
  BEGIN
    EXEC Next_Invoice_Number Inserted.base, @invoiceNumber OUTPUT
    INSERT INTO Invoice (base, invoiceNumber) 
                VALUES (Inserted.base, @invoiceNumber)
  END
```

(obviously, you have more columns, including others that should be auto-populated - you'll need to fill them in)
...which you can then use by simply saying:

```
INSERT INTO Invoice (base) VALUES('A');
```

So what have we done?  Mostly, all this work was about shrinking the number of rows locked by a transaction.  Until this `INSERT` is committed, there are only two rows locked:

- The row in `Invoice_Sequence` maintaining the sequence number
- The row in `Invoice` for the new invoice.

All other rows for a particular `base` are free - they can be updated or queried at will (deleting information out of this kind of system tends to make accountants nervous).  You probably need to decide what should happen when queries would normally include the pending invoice...

Comment: I really like the fact that you give extensive and professional looking explanation to what you are doing with good code examples. The only think I am still wondering about is how much would the performance of the blocking suffer, and wouldn't be a better idea to implement in the data abstraction layer just a loop that takes the last available number, tries to insert and if already used to repeat the whole thing until it inserts the proper one. That way we may achieve worse performance when there are racing conditions but at least we know we avoid blocking and triggers which are more dangerous

Comment: You'd essentially run into the same problem.  You couldn't safely read anything unless it was committed... and the inserts couldn't be committed until the same work had been performed anyways.  That is, the limiting factor with my version/your idea isn't the read, it's the **write**.  The original had problems with reads because we were locking 'unrelated' records.  Doing it your way would actually slow things down and make it more difficult to deal with, what with multiple roundtrips between the db and the application layer.

Comment: I suppose if I need more complicated logic for the generation (let's say adding some prefixes to the invoice number integer) I still have to do that in the procedure.

Comment: yeah, although you likely need to store that information too.  If you prefix it with `year`, for example, do you need to restart every year?  If so, you need to store a separate row every year.  You might need to check with accounting about if generation should always add the "current" value, or if there are cases where you need the next/previous value instead.  But this is an exercise left up to the reader.

Comment: I tried the solution and it does not work. Reading the answer, I was wondering what this syntax was (can you really call a Stored Proc as a column of a `SELECT` ?) I tried it to see if it was something I did not know, and no, you can't do that with a SP : `SELECT base, Next_Invoice_Number(base) FROM Inserted;` You would need a UDF for that, but UDF do not allow INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and MERGE. Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: @MaxiWheat - Ah, thanks for letting me know!  Not sure quite why I picked that form originally.  Anyways, take the revised trigger for a spin, that looks like it should work.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I don't think it would work on a batch insert (the trigger fires only once per statement, even if that statement inserts many rows)

Comment: @MaxiWheat - no, you're right, it would have problems with multiple rows.  Besides the fact this answer was mostly an example of how to do this, bulk inserts are less likely in this case anyways, given what the data represents.  Bulk inserting invoices probably implies other things about your program, which would require additional work regardless.

Comment: Clearly described solution. However, unfortunately, the proposed trigger throws: Incorrect syntax near '.' on Inserted.base for the EXEC line

Answer (score 0):

you can use the trigger for before insert and assign the next value by taking the max(id) with "base" filter which is "A" in this case.

That will give you the max(id) value as 2 and than increment it by max(id)+1. now push the new value to the "id" field. before insert.

I think this may help you

MSSQL Triggers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: You will still get race conditions with this approach unless you wrap it in a transaction and additionally raise the isolation level above the default.  You may in fact have to raise the isolation level to Serializable, which has onerous performance implications.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: you are right we should also take care of isolation levels.if not we may not get the actual uncommitted data..

Comment: Specifically the problem is, another session could fire the same trigger at the same time, produce the same `MAX(id)+1` value and then try to commit it.  One of them will have to fail, and trigger and session would receive that failure.  Serializable stops that (I beleieve) but at a high performance cost.

Comment: Currently what I do is the same but in the code which is even slower and increases the chance for race conditions. In SQL Server 2012 there is a SEQUENCE but I am not sure how it works.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: as we are talking about trigger and not the procedure, I hope it should work as trigger will only execute one task at a time that to insert. so I think it will work.

Comment: No that is incorrect.  The same trigger can be executed simultaneously by any number of different SQL sessions.

Comment: @zigi to use SEQUENCE, i believe that you would have to create one for every distinct `base` value.

Comment: I dont think you can achieve this by using SEQUENCE, sequence object generates a sequential number when ever called regardless of from where its being called, it is useful to implement identity value across multiple tables but I guess pretty useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

### Test Table

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
   ( base CHAR(1),
     id   INT
   )
GO
```

### Trigger Definition

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_Populate_ID
ON dbo.MyTable 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO MyTable (base,id)
SELECT i.base, ISNULL(MAX(mt.id),0) +1 AS NextValue
  FROM inserted i left join MyTable mt
  on i.base = mt.base
  GROUP BY i.base

END
```

### Test

Execute the following statement multiple times and you will see the next values available in that group will be assigned to ID.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
('A'),
('B'),
('C')
GO

SELECT * FROM MyTable
GO
```

Comment: Thanks a lot M.Ali but can you tell me with 100% certainty that if I execute to concurrent requests it is not gonna produce a racing condition?

Comment: This is essentially the same thing that @arjun already suggested and suffers from the same problems.

Comment: I see @RBarryYoung, do you know where I can read about the performance issues with the Serializable level?

Comment: Very well said RBarryYoung, It is most likely to get into race condition will subsequent inserts.

Comment: Having Serialzable Transaction Isolation level will give you much bigger things to worry, Deadlocks is one of them :) for me a no go zone.

Comment: @zigi heres a good article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/05/16/serializable-vs-snapshot-isolation-level.aspx

Comment: No, deadlocks are actually *less* likely with Serializable.  Severely increased ***blocking*** is the real problem.

Comment: ops sorry slip of tongue I meant Blocking :) When users who only want to read data are just sat there for other users to finish their reads. `Danger Zone` for any OLTP application.