# SQL Server composite key custom Auto Increment in child field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express. I have created the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[logis_location] 
( [loc_id] int identity  NOT NULL 
  , [loc_name] varchar(50)  NOT NULL   )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rev_bill] 
( [bill_id] int identity  NOT NULL   ,
  [loc_id] int  NOT NULL   )

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[rev_bill] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [rev_bill_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [bill_id] , [loc_id] )

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[rev_bill] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [logis_location_rev_bill_FK1] 
FOREIGN KEY ( [loc_id] )
```

THe bill_id is auto incrementing ,But bill table have composite key based on location table loc_id which is foreign Key. 
This resulting following output

```
   bill_id  loc_id
    1        1
    2        1
    3        2
    4        2
    5        1

    6        3

    7        2
```

However expected outcome is

```
   bill_id  loc_id

    1        1

    2        1

    1        2

    2        2

    3        1

    1        3

    3        2
```

I want to increment the location specific  bill_id in most safest way.It means when inserting new bill ,the bill id should be incremented ,but considering the loc_id.As given above, If there is bill for the given location (eg:loc_id =4), first bill for that location should have bill_id 1,and next one should be 2. This is Client requirement. 
 Please provide me some guide line.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - can you try to **explain** in English what you're trying to do, and what you're seeing instead? Just dumping piles of data on us hoping we'll *guess* what you want isn't very helpful......

Comment: I don't see any difference between the current result and expected outcome?

Comment: Do you _need_ the values of `bill_id` to repeat for each `loc_id` (and presumably have no gaps)?  barring certain specific situations, it'd be better to just have the column with a single autogen value, meaning each one would have a unique value...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse No ,,for given loc_id all the bill Ids should be Unique,,,loc-id and bill_id both is the composite key for bill table.If we take only bill_id,,for bill table(rev_bill) it is not unique,,,

Comment: An identity column won't generate duplicate values, so I'm not sure how you're getting repeating values here (this only covers _generation_).  If you only need non-duplicate per-`loc_id`, a simple identity column will work just fine.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks ,,I understand identity column won't generate duplicate values ,,,As for my requirement both loc_id(forign key ) and bill_id shroud be primary key and the bill-id should be incremented based on location (loc-id). As indicate in adjusted question,, Is there a more secure way (than ordering and take top)to do this increment in SQL server 2012

Comment: I actually [answered a similar question recently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24184749/812837).  However, you want to avoid this if possible (due to the need for serialization); only do this if you are **required** (as in, business need, not technical) to have multiple sequences with no gaps/restarting values.  If you just need some sort of db-only, internal id, just use a regular auto-gen column, and don't worry about the gaps/non-restarting values.