# How to create a concurrency-safe and gap-free counter in Db2

Tags: sql, db2

I understand that identity columns and sequences cannot guarantee a gap-free counter as generated numbers are lost during a rollback.
So I'm trying to maintain my own counter. 
Is the following sufficient to avoid that any other thread or system (e.g. data sharing) can potentially interfere with this update/select sequence:

```
SELECT counter FROM FINAL TABLE ( UPDATE cnt_table SET counter=counter+1 WHERE counter_id=? )
```

Or is there a better way to create such a counter ? 
Formerly, I thought a sequence of

```
SELECT counter FROM cnt_table WHERE counter_id=? FOR UPDATE OF counter WITH RS
UPDATE cnt_table SET counter=counter+1 WHERE couner_id=?
```

is safely incrementing the counter while avoiding that concurrent transactions are even able to query the counter while the first transaction is not finished. Then I read that the SELECT FROM FINAL TABLE combination with UPDATE in a single statement is a better way. So will it also create appropriate locks so that concurrent transactions will wait ?
Note: I'm using dynamic SQL inside a stored procedure. The code needs to work on Db2 LUW and Db2 on Z. Distributed unit-of-work support is not required.

Comment: You cannot guarantee gap-free at database-layer alone, because of the risk of transaction-rollback. It requires co-operation at application layer to ensure gap-free and monotonic counter values, to recover from database-layer rollbacks when they happen for whatever reasons, especially in distributed-unit-of-work scenarios.

Comment: @mao, sorry, I don't get it. Incrementing the counter (let's say from 1 to 2) is part of a transaction. So if transaction rolls back increment is undone and next transaction increments again from 1 to 2, until such a transaction commits. The only condition I'm aware of is that the transaction needs to hold a lock (update lock?) so that no concurrent transaction can even query the current counter for the increment while the first transaction is not finished. So I don't get why application needs to co-op? <br/>I also edited the question to provide more context (e.g distr uow not needed)

Comment: Are there any performance requirements or is the only requirement "gap-free"? Does it need to run in MPP or data-sharing / pureScale?

Comment: @data_henrik: yes performance has to step back, "gap-free" is a must. The solution needs to work in data-sharing and MPP ...

Answer (score 0):

(I've previously posted [an answer for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184749/sql-server-unique-composite-key-of-two-field-with-second-field-auto-increment/24196374#24196374) with some additional bits, which should be translatable)

Eh, it's not going to matter too much which version you choose, because the primary guarantor of the system is going to be the isolation level of the transaction, not whether you have one or two statements.  In some ways, I wouldn't be surprised if the underlying mechanism was the same for both.  And you're going to want to be explicit about your transactions, here, to make it obvious what's going on.  (Note that you'll need at least Read Stability if you've pre-populated the ids, probably Repeatable Read if you haven't)

Keep in mind that, in most cases, getting the answer back from the `SELECT` isn't the end - you're usually inserting that value in at least one table, or logging it to send it somewhere (eg, to a receipt-mailing program - although failure in this case is more problematic), any of which might fail.  In those cases, you most likely need to `ROLLBACK`.

Personally, I think I'd use the change-table-reference, just because it makes it a little cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. You basically confirm what I also concluded from the docs: Count yourself and ensure correct isolation.
I ended up with the two separate statements, cause no one answered the question if the 'SELECT FROM FINAL TABLE(UPDATE ...)' automatically sets required locks or how I have to extend my example so that it has the same effects as the two separate statements ...