# IBM DB2 + Doctrine - Auto increment in composite primary keys

Tags: laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine, db2, laravel-5.4

My problem is easy to understand and many mentioned here in Stackoverflow with references to Doctrine docs.

> Every entity with a composite key cannot use an id generator other
>   than "ASSIGNED". That means the ID fields have to have their values
>   assigned before you call EntityManager#persist($entity).

I tried this, getting last generated ID, adding + 1 to its value and persisting entity. The problem is that a third party software that uses the same IBM DB2 database, cannot add a row, because the auto increment index is not updated when I insert a row in that way.

Is there a way to make this work or a way to update the table auto increment index?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

In order to help you to better understand what I want/have to achieve, I will show you my example.

EntityClass

```
class Entity
{
    /**
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(type="string", name="serie")
     */
     protected $serie;

    /**
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="reference")
     *  @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
     protected $reference;
     // More code...
}
```

Multiple primary keys are allowed by doctrine, but for some reason, when I fill the entity this way

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->set("serie", date('Y')); // Custom setter that search the property and sets the value. In this case, current year as string
 // More assignements, except for the autoincrement value
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

It throws an exception saying that one of the ids is not filled and MUST be filled in a composite key entity, but it is an auto increment column and I need to make it work that way, find a way to get the next auto increment value for the table or update auto increment value for the table in IBM DB2. If not, the other third party software will crash if I get the max value of the auto increment column, increase that value by one and assign it to the entity manually.

The query:

```
SELECT presence FROM DB2ADMIN.PRESENCES WHERE serie LIKE 2017 ORDER BY presence DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

If you need any further information, let me know.

Comment: I think they're mostly speaking when you have a composite key where the "autogenerated" part repeats _per the rest of the key_.  That is, both `(keyColumnAValueA, 0)` and `(keyColumnAValueB, 0)` are valid.  No database I'm aware of will autogen here - the expectation is that autogenerated keys are fully surrogate - standins for other keys, and the values themselves are meaningless; repeating ones imply that the value has some meaning.  What is this ID for, then?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thanks for your comment. I don't follow you at all. Maybe I'm mistaken when talking about composite keys or truelly I don't understand what you are talking about, sorry :( I'll update my question so you can get a better view of what I want to achieve

Comment: Okay... do you want the value of `$reference` to be unique for the whole table, or unique per `$serie`?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse unique per serie

Comment: Okay, and do you need any guarantee about the sequence itself?  Are gaps allowed, or not at all?  What's supposed to happen in the event of a `ROLLBACK`, should the sequence not consume the value that was generated and inserted into the table?

Comment: Yes, I need to guarantee that the auto increment is updated in the table and keeps the sequence. I don't know what do you mean with gaps, but if you mean if I care about having a `$reference = 1` and `$reference = 3` instead of 2, I don't care. I don't care if the `$reference` keeps increasing and we do not revert the last `$reference` in the sequence, but if it can be done "easily", I will accept it :) In fact, the third party software does not handle `ROLLBACKS` and when users presence table crashed on friday, we had to re-register the presence of all users and fix times... Horrible

Comment: ...uh, what do you mean it doesn't handle rollbacks?  Are transactions not a thing?  Note that given [this page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html) it looks like you can't mark the column as generated at all, and it explicitly says you have to set it beforehand, which is actually a right pain (since it would be nice to have a db trigger add it for you).

Comment: The third party software, from which I'm not the developer, does not do transactions. Yes, its a bad shitty software, but it was just a comment xD I don't care about that. I want that my laravel app with doctrine handles auto increment with multiple primary keys, "that's all". Btw, I work with transactions. Answering to the generated column, I can setup a column as ID with generated value when only one primary key. The problem is with composite keys, thats why I am here, to know how can I handle that on IBM DB2. How can I assign manually an autoincrement value and update the IBM DB2

Comment: table column to let it know that the value inserted is a valid value, force update the autoincrement value or retrieve the next autoincrement value from the DBMS and update the table column autoincrement value

Comment: ...first off, `DEFAULT` is ever only going to insert a single, statically known value (which the table declares), which isn't going to help you - the usual thing to do is _leave it off the column list_.  Secondly, `INSERT`ing anything into an `AUTOINCREMENT` column is a recipe for disaster, since it won't update the backing increment store.  But you can't use `AUTOINCREMENT` anyways, since that doesn't reset, so I'm not sure  what you're trying here.  I'm somewhat reasonably sure SQL 1-indexes just about everything, so that might not be the real column.  Always list columns for `INSERT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways to do this, but since you don't have access to transactions (and apparently don't care about gaps), I don't recommend one of them.

The first way, which I'm recommending you not use, is to create a table to hold the generated value, incrementing that, and returning it.  I [previously answered a question about this for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196374/812837), but the concept should translate.  Note that some of the utility is lost since you can't generate the value in a trigger, but should still work.  The primary remaining issue is that the table represents a bottleneck, which you're not getting much benefit out of.

The second way is just to use a separate `SEQUENCE` for each year.  This is somewhat problematic in that you'd need to create the object each year, but would be much faster to get a number.  You'd also be essentially guaranteed to have gaps.

Note that I'm always a little suspicious of primary keys where the value is incremented and has value, especially if gaps are allowed.

Comment: Thanks. After looking into the DB, the third party software has a table called "counters". It references the ID for the table. I only had to update the reference in that table. Now it works like a charm. Thanks for your time