# Stored procedure with AS MERGE not returning anything?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**EDIT**: Sequential invoice numbering is the law in multiple countries.

**EDIT**: Poor variable naming on my part suggested I wanted to use my generated Id as a key. This is not the case. Should have stuck with 'invoiceNumber'.

---

I have the exact same question as posed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196374/1980516

However, since the proposed solution threw a syntax error, I've adapted it to use a cursor.

First, there is the stored procedure that generates a new Nr, for a given Business+Year combination:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_NextInvoiceNumber @businessId INT, @year INT, @Nr NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT 
AS MERGE INTO InvoiceNextNumbers ini
    USING (VALUES (@businessId, @year)) Incoming(BusinessId, Year)
        ON Incoming.BusinessId = ini.BusinessId AND Incoming.Year = ini.Year
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ini.Nr = ini.Nr + 1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (BusinessId, Year, Nr) 
VALUES(@businessId, @year, 1)

OUTPUT INSERTED.Nr;
```

Then, using that stored procedure, I've created an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG_GenerateInvoiceNumber ON Invoices INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
  BEGIN

    DECLARE @BusinessId INT
    DECLARE @InvoiceId INT
    DECLARE @BillingDate DATETIME2(7)

    -- Cursors are expensive, but I don't see any other way to call the stored procedure per row
    -- Mitigating factor: Mostly, we're only inserting one Invoice at a time
    DECLARE InsertCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT BusinessId, Id, BillingDate FROM INSERTED

    OPEN InsertCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCursor
    INTO @BusinessId, @InvoiceId, @BillingDate
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @year INT
        SET @year = year(@BillingDate)

        DECLARE @Number NVARCHAR(MAX)
        EXEC PROC_NextInvoiceNumber @BusinessId, @year, @Number OUTPUT
        -- SET @Number = 'this works'

        INSERT INTO Invoices (BusinessId, Id, BillingDate, Number) 
            VALUES (@BusinessId, @InvoiceId, @BillingDate, @Number)

        FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCursor
        INTO @BusinessId, @InvoiceId, @BillingDate
    END
    CLOSE InsertCursor
    DEALLOCATE InsertCursor

    END
```

If I uncomment `SET @Number = 'this works'`, then in my database that exact string ('this works') is successfully set in Invoice.Number.

Somehow, my OUTPUT parameter is not set and I can't figure out why not.. Can someone shed a light on this?

*EDIT* update in response to comments (thank you):

- I have a composite key (BusinessId, Id) for Invoice. The desired end result is a unique Invoice <s>Identifier</s> Number of the form '20180001' that is a continuous sequence of numbers *within* the businessId. So business 1 has invoice Numbers 20180001, 20180002, 20180003 and business 2 **also** has invoice numbers 20180001, 20180002, 20180003. (But different composite primary keys)
- I don't want that cursor either, but I saw no other way within the framework as suggested by the question I refer to up above.
- Manual call of PROC_NextInvoiceNumber with existing business id and year returns NULL.
- If I try to set Id in PROC_NextInvoiceNumber, I get `A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).` if I set it inside the MERGE or `The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.Nr" could not be bound.` if I set outside the MERGE.

Comment: Where is the code for PROC_NextInvoiceIdentifier? I cringe when I see a cursor inside an instead of trigger. And the body of that trigger is in a loop so you can get the key value. That is a huge red flag that something is not designed well. And resorting to a cursor because of syntax error? You should fix the code, not resort to a cursor.

Comment: There's no `AS MERGE`. MERGE is a command just like INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. Stored procedure results *can't* be captured except to insert the results into a table. Why did you use a *cursor* in the trigger though, istead of writing the MERGE inside it? You can put the MERGE in a subquery or CTE and insert its results into Invoices

Comment: BTW MERGE will return results *both* for inserted and updated rows. This means you'll end up with duplicates in your `Invoices` table. Why don't you just put separate INSERT/UPDATE statements in the trigger? The result will be a lot cleaner

Comment: You aren't setting/changing the value of the OUTPUT parameter `@id` anywhere in your stored procedure code.    Does that procedure return expected results when you run it by itself (outside the trigger)?

Comment: PS: SQL Server has [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql). `PROC_NextInvoiceIdentifier` could be replaced with a `NEXT VALUE FOR MyInvoiceSequence` in a SELECT or VALUES clause

Comment: Essentially [duplicate question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135032/id-with-the-format-yyyynnnnnn-with-the-nnnnnn-part-restarting-each-year) at dba.stackexchange.com. You can restart the sequence with a job once a year `ALTER SEQUENCE CountBy1 RESTART WITH 1;` or create a different sequence per year

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've updated the question. I see you have ideas on how to approach this, avoiding the cursor and other things, but I'm having trouble envisioning what it is I should do. I've been avoiding stored procedures as much as possible in favor of putting logic in my service layer, my SQL knowledge is rusty... I do believe this belongs here, because the Id should be set once and not change (e.g. if an invoice with an earlier date is inserted, the existing invoices should not be renumbered)

Comment: You are hiding data in your key. This is a bad design decision. You should have a column in your table for year if that is important. And most likely an identity would be the best choice here since it is just some number.

Comment: @SeanLange Year is just one part of BillingDate. In that sense, this is derived data, but I don't want to recalculate the identifiers every time I retrieve a record. As for identity: How do you propose that I create an identity in such a way that every business has its own set of consecutive invoice ids, starting at 1? As far as I know, you can't do this out of the box in SQL Server.

Comment: I would actually propose that keeping an incremental number per business is not a good practice and that you shouldn't do that. Why do you have a need for an incremental key per business per year? And if you need that you really should not be combining multiple pieces of data together like this. This is violating 1NF and is a serious pain to deal with. I think you are putting too much emphasis on what is essentially a random number.

Comment: @SeanLange Sequential invoice numbering is the law in multiple countries. Do you have a suggestion on how it should be done? (in this composite key BusinessId-Id case)

Comment: You could use a sequence as already suggested. You would just need a separate sequence for each business. Or you could use an identity in your table and another column to be used on the actual invoice. There is no law that says that the sequential number on your invoice has to be the key in your database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165581/discussion-between-diana-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OUTPUT parameter is never set. You are using the [OUTPUT clause of the MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) statement to create a result set. This is unrelated to assigning a value to a parameter.

```
MERGE INTO..
USING ... ON ...
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ...
OUTPUT INSERTED.Nr;  /* <-- HERE this is the OUTPUT *clause*  */
```

Change the code to actually assign something to @Nr:

```
SET @Nr = ...
```

The typical way is to use the OUTPUT clause to store the desired value into a *table variable* and then assign the value to the desired output *variable:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Nr NVARCHAR(MAX));
MERGE INTO..
USING ... ON ...
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ...
OUTPUT INSERTED.Nr INTO @t;

SELECT @Nr = Nr FROM @t;
```

Comment: What is the "output clause *of* the insert statement"? I have an output clause in the stored procedure and an insert statement in the trigger, but not an output clause in an insert statement. Furthermore, if I do "SET OUTPUT = " or "@Id =" I get `A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon`. What I am doing follows the syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql as far as I can tell. Can you please show me how it's done?

Comment: @Diana I updated the post to better show what I mean.

Comment: That was it! I really didn't see that that was what I was missing. Thanks!